# Jackson save a nested object to database

Tags: java, json, hibernate, jackson

I am using jackson for converting a json to java objects.

java object:

```
class Person{
   Long id;
   String name;
   City city;
}

class City{
   Long id;
   String cityName;
}
```

jcson conversion:

```
List<Person> personList = objectMapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<List<Person>>() { });
```

When saving the person, i get the following error:

```
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: model.City
```

Can you please advise?

Comment: can you add your mapping + your dao ??

Comment: dao:
session.saveOrUpdate(person);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to include `cascade="all"`  (if using xml) or `cascade=CascadeType.ALL` (if using annotations) on City attribute in your Person entity.

this is due to the fact that you are trying to save an entity which is referenced to an unsaved one.

if you dont want to delete the City record when deleting a Person
you have to pass by theses steps: 
1- getting the city from database : `City city=session.get(id,City.class);`

2- setting person's city : `Person p=new person(); p.setCity(city);`

3- save the Person object.

Comment: When using cascade deleting the person will delete the city, which isn't true in this case since a city can be applied for a few users. The data of the city is stored in the db already, i dont need to re save it